# Returning a value when an AsyncTask has finished

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, interface, android-asynctask

I know that I can use interfaces as delegates to do things while performing task, I also know that I can use `get()` to make an AsyncTask synchronous, But I don't want to block the UI thread.

I used `AsyncTask` with `OkHttp` to upload a file and get a result like this:

```
static class UploadFile extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    private TaskInterface<String, Float> delegate = null;

    private String url;
    private File file;
    private MediaType fileType;

    private String ret = "NULL";

    UploadFile(String url, File file, MediaType fileType, TaskInterface<String, Float> delegate){
        this.delegate = delegate;
        this.url = url;
        this.file = file;
        this.fileType = fileType;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        if (delegate != null){
            delegate.onPreCompleteTask();
            Log.d("UPLOADING:", "File : " + file.getName());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void...voids) {

            RequestBody body = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                    .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                    .addFormDataPart("upload", file.getName(),RequestBody.create(fileType, file))
                    .build();

            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(url)
                    .post(body)
                    .build();
            try {
                Response response = okhttpclient.newCall(request).execute();
                ret = response.body().string();
            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("HttpClient", "Upload: " + e.getMessage());
            }

        return ret;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (delegate != null){
            delegate.onCompleteTask(result);
            Log.d("ON UPLOAD POST EXECUTE", result);
        }
    }
}
```

then I create the task in method like this:

```
Boolean validateVCode(File file){

    final boolean[] boolResult = new boolean[1];

            new UploadFile("http://localhost/doThings.php",
                        file,
                        myMediaType,
                        new TaskInterface<String, Float>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onPreCompleteTask(){
                                processDialog.show();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCompleteTask(String result) {
                                processDialog.dismiss();
                                boolResult[0] = result.contains("true");
                            }
                        }).execute();

    return boolResult[0];
}
```

But the problem is that the task gets thrown in the background and the method continues working, so in the first execution of the method it returns the default value of boolResult[0] which is false, but in the second execution (After the task finishes) it changes the return value to whatever is result of the task. So it takes two method executions to get the desired value.

Is there any work-around to make a method wait for the task without blocking the main thread?

Comment: You can't block a method without blocking the thread it's being ran in. All libraries including SDK itself use listener pattern for that reason.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So, can I create a different thread and block it without any performance penalties?

Comment: no performance penalties on the main thread? - yes

Comment: Although I don't think it is recommended to create your own threads on android

Comment: Use AsyncTask or AsyncTaskLoader - managing thread to be activity lifecycle aware and report result on UI thread is a problem that is already solved by those.

Comment: You don't need an AsyncTask to use OkHTTP... It already has Callback functions

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @SteelToe.

Comment: I'm already using AsyncTask...@Pawel

Comment: I'm using AsyncTask for some extra work too, not just okhttp. @cricket_007

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to block the UI thread, then you have to let the work done in parallel. In that case it is not possible to return the result from the UI thread.

[image: illustration]

There for your primary question

> Is there any work-around to make a method wait for the task without
>   blocking the main thread?

itself doesn't make any sense.

### The solution

- Make filter a void method.
- wrap everything you want to do with the
  result in another method (`onResult(boolean result)`) and call it from `onCompleteTask()`.
- Do whatever
  you want to do in there.

Comment: There's a problem with your solution. The last method returns a boolean which I need to check something so that I'm calling it like that:

    if (validateVCode(someFile)) {
        doSomeWork();
    }

Comment: Just call it as validateVCode(someFile) onResult(boolean result){if(result){doSomeWork();}} that is what I am telling you.

Comment: The problem is still there, the result isn't set until the AsyncTask has finished it's work.

Comment: Like it is impossible to have the result before an action is completed in real life, you can't get the result before the task becomes completed.

Comment: Read my solution to the problem in the answer below.

Comment: That is exactly what i suggest. Read the second point in my answer again

Comment: Yes it's partially accepted, and I put it first, but it doesn't solve all problems, so I searched for another solution online. which is RxJava. Thank you so much for your support.

Answer (score 0):

I think that I found two solutions to my problem:

- **Make the call to the checking method inside "onCompleteTask(String result)":**

  `@Override
  public void onCompleteTask(String result){
      processDialog.dismiss();
      checkingMethod(result.contains("true"));
  }`
- **Implement RxJava:** which is explained [here.](https://www.toptal.com/android/functional-reactive-android-rxjava)